# Getting currentUser in post-function Jira

Tags: groovy, jira

I have the following line of code

`String currentUser = ((WorkflowContext)transientVars.get("context")).getCaller();`

Then I proceed to call

`(comment != "") && commentManager.create(parent, currentUser, comment, true);`

My question is, that `CommentManager` now requires the `applicationUser` object instead of a `String`. So how do I get the `currentUser` that would return the `applicationUser`.

[Question on Atlassian board](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/39786064/postfunction-currentuser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComponentAccessor.userManager.getUserByName(userName)` will give you the `ApplicationUser` for a username string.

Comment: I think you need to call it like this by the way. `ComponentAccessor.getUserManager().getUserByName(userName)`

Comment: Then you are thinking wrong. It is Groovy, `ComponentAccessor.userManager` is automatically mapped to `ComponentAccessor.getUserManager()` or `ComponentAccessor.setUserManager(userManager)` depending on whether you read or write the property. ;-)

Comment: Alright. My Jira decided to throw an error my way and was fixed by calling it fully. So possibly something that's out of my hands.

Comment: Then you must have a strange JIRA version, I use this style in JIRA Scripts for ages and it always worked fine. But however it works for you.